# There is no Einstein in Einstein Analytics

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I saw that "Einstein-analytics" is a tag synonym for "einstein," which is not true. "Einstein-analytics" is the new name for Wave. E-A is a way to visualize Einstein output, if desired, but it has no inherent AI/predictive features.

I don't have permissions to remove or remap synonyms, so I don't know how to go about fixing this.

"Wave" should map to "Einstein-Analytics" and not to "Einstein."

Can somebody help me, please? Or if I can do it myself and just need it approved, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree.

- [Salesforce-Einstein is now a synonyms for einstein](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/einstein/synonyms).
- [analytics-cloud and wave are now synonyms for einstein-analytics](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/einstein-analytics/synonyms).